# Bondal counter example to the Jordan-Holder property in derived categories

Tags: derived-categories

Can anybody give me the reference where this counter-example is explained in detail?. Consists on the following
Bondal considered a quiver $Q$ with some relations and proved that $D(Q)$ has two different semi-orthogonal decompositions, of length 3 and 2. 
Also, I don't know anything about quivers, do you think that there is a way to understand this result without a lot of background? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.0903

Comment:  I already knew that papper, the thing is that there it explains what Bondal proved, but doesn't give a detailed proof nor a reference

Comment: The reason for nonextendability is the fact that the Euler form $\chi(-,-)$ on the orthogonal subcategory $P^\perp$ is skew-symmetric, and so $P^\perp$ does not have exceptional objects.